# MySQl IF NOT EXISTS, CREATE Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I come from a background with Microsoft SQl using their Server management studio. I have recently switched to mysql and am looking to create a stored procedure with the same method I use with MSSQL. I want to create a procedure if it does not exists because I prefer that to dropping if exists. Below is the syntax I would use in MSSQL. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT 
    1 
FROM 
    sysobjects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE 
    [type] = 'P' AND name = 'Sproc'
)
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sproc AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Sproc
(
    @Sproc_Params
)
AS
BEGIN
.... --Sproc code
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in `mysql.proc` to see if a procedure exists.

```
SELECT db, name FROM mysql.proc WHERE db = 'dbo' AND name = 'Sproc';
```

However, in MySQL, you cannot `ALTER PROCEDURE` to replace the procedure body. You can only change a few attributes of the procedure. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-procedure.html for details.

So you will have to drop and create the procedure anyway, if you want to change its parameters or its body.